# Select highest record within a group

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Can you please tell how to select the highest record in a set of records. For example in the below table I want to get only the record which has the latest date (in bold).

| TYP | SEQ | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1900-01-01 |
| A | 1 | 2002-01-06 |
| **A** | **1** | **2021-02-01** |
| A | 2 | 1900-01-01 |
| A | 2 | 2003-12-01 |
| A | 2 | 2004-12-05 |
| **A** | **2** | **2021-02-21** |
| A | 2 | 2021-01-06 |
| A | 3 | 2015-05-17 |
| A | 3 | 2017-11-26 |
| A | 3 | 2019-11-10 |
| **A** | **3** | **2021-01-01** |

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please share table names and queries you have already tried. What is the database you're using?

Comment: Haven't you tried anything yourself? Where are you stuck? What is your DBMS? You should always tag your SQL questions with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First `group by` the table with `SEQ`, then join the table to the same table and create the rows with `ROW_NUMBER()`and sort by date, and then show the results in the output with records whose row number is one.

```
WITH resultTable AS (
SELECT 
RT.TYP,
RT.SEQ,
RT.DATE,   
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY RT.SEQ 
                         ORDER BY RT.DATE DESC ) AS [ROW NUMBER]
FROM MyTable RT
Inner JOIN 
(
  SELECT SEQ
  FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY SEQ
) LT ON RT.SEQ = LT.SEQ)
select resultTable.TYP,resultTable.SEQ,resultTable.DATE from resultTable
WHERE resultTable.[ROW NUMBER] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple window function should do it:

```
select typ, seq, date
from (
  select typ, seq, date, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by typ, seq order by date desc) as rn
  from the_table
) t
where rn = 1
order by typ, seq;
```